# javascript using variables in style.display

Tags: javascript

I have a webpage that overlays village and guard tower locations on an imagemap for a game.
I created a javascript function to show and hide the transparent .png grid and the legend.
I would like to also use this function to show/hide the guard towers. Script works just fine but when I try to hide the towers the script only picks the first tower in the database.

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
function toggleLayer(whichLayer){
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var e = document.getElementById(whichLayer)
        e.style.display = e.style.display == "none" ? "block" : "none";
    }
}
</script>
```

I then have a button to call the function.

```
<form method="get" action="javascript:toggleLayer('tower');"><button class="botbuttprefs" type="submit">Show/Hide Towers</button></form>
ECHO "<div class='type' id='tower' style='top:",$GETy[$e]-2,"px; left:",$GETx[$e]-2,"px; width:4px; height:4px; z-index:2; background-color:black'></div>";
```

Comment: shouldn't you use some class to point more than one tower? `getElementById` retrieves just one element.. you can see it here: http://jsfiddle.net/q3ceD/

Comment: Is there a browser with meaningful market share that *doesn't* have `document.getElementById`?

Comment: Please, edit your question and put the code there. People will look there first before reading the comments, and it helps finding the problem.

Comment: Can you please also post the HTML for the `tower layer`? It's just a big div with `id = tower` containing `n` tower elements or each tower has `id = tower`?

Comment: It is multiple divs with id='tower'

Comment: Is there a specific reason to check document.getElementById ? or it is just a typo?

Comment: @user2977156 `id` should be unique in the page, you probably better use `class` instead. Please google `document.getElementsByClassName`

Answer (score 0):

It's not entirely clear what question you're asking.

`document.getElementById` works with an id value and returns only a single element and there should only ever be one item in your page with a given id.  So, if you were expecting it to somehow magically work with multiple elements with the same id, it will not.

To select multiple elements in the page, there are a number of ways to do that but the simplest would be to give each element a common class name.  You can then use `document.querySelectorAll(".myClass")` and it will return a list of DOM nodes which you can then iterate over to apply a change to all of them.

You may also want to know that reading `element.style.display` may return an empty string if there is no explicit style set on that node.  `element.style.display` does not return a setting that may be in effect because of a default condition or because of a style sheet rule.  If you wanted to get the actual value in effect, you would need to use [`getComputedStyle()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.getComputedStyle).

---

Also, there is no reason to use this:

```
if (document.getElementById)
```

All browsers have that method.

Comment: keep in mind that `getElementsByClassName` is not supported by all browsers/browsers version: http://caniuse.com/getelementsbyclassname

Comment: @BeNdErR - if you want to support IE8, you can either use `document.querySelectorAll()` or use a shim for `getElementsByClassName()` for old versions of IE.  The point of this post is you use a class name and you get a nodeList of items rather than an id with a single element.